# Is it real to install any IDE on elementary OS, like NetBeans, Code:Blocks, etc

Tags: programming, ide, java

I'm about to choose this Unix-based system for my everyday tasks. By the way, I've started to learn basics of programming, so this is gonna be cool to use this smooth, stylish system to browse internet and study.

Answer (score 1):

There are many IDEs available for elementary OS. I personally use Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA, Atom, VS Code, Scratch, and Gnome Builder. Bottomline: Whatever language you are working in or whatever your development needs are, you're covered.